# IR HEX comparison

Tags: c, arduino

I am new to c programming and trying to compare IR HEX strings. I am getting- error: lvalue required as left operand of assignment.

I thing my problem is around line 31.
Here is the code:

```
/* IRremote: IRrecvDemo - demonstrates receiving IR codes with IRrecv
* An IR detector/demodulator must be connected to the input RECV_PIN.
* Version 0.1 July, 2009
* Copyright 2009 Ken Shirriff
* http://arcfn.com
*/

#include <IRremote.h>

int RECV_PIN = 11;
IRrecv irrecv(RECV_PIN);
decode_results results;
String  stringAppleUp;  



void setup()
 {

  Serial.begin(9600);
  irrecv.enableIRIn(); // Start the receiver
 }

void loop() {

if (irrecv.decode(&results)) {
  Serial.println(results.value, HEX);
  Serial.println ("See it");
  stringAppleUp = string('77E150BC');  //apple remote up button

if (    ????        = stringAppleUp)  {
  Serial.println("yes");
  }
else
  {
  Serial.println("No");
  }
irrecv.resume(); // Receive the next value
  }
}
```

the line: if (??? = stringAppleUp)
I don't know what variable to put in where the ??? is.

Thanks for the help.
Will

Comment: Uh, how should we know what variable you want to put there? But there are two problems: `if ( a = b )` doesn't check whether `a` is equal to `b`, and `string('77E150BC')` probably doesn't do what you think it does either.

Comment: Is this C or C++? (The body of the question says C so I edited the tags, but looking at the code I'm not sure.) In any event, you probably mean `==`, not `=` in an `if` condition.

Comment: To be honest I'm not sure if its c or c++.  The code is for Arduino IDE v1

Comment: I would guess the ???? should be results.value

Comment: `"lvalue required"` - translation: you are trying to assign a value to the left hand side of an equation (as in `x = 1`), but the thing to the left (`x` in my example) isn't something that you can assign a value to. Usually that means it's a constant - as in `1 = x`. As was pointed out before, in C you use `==` for equality, `=` for assignment.

Answer (score 7):

You are over thinking the goal. 
First results.value returns a uint32_t, not a string.
Second the "String" is different then an array of char's (aka "string"). Notice the Capital S.

```
stringAppleUp = String('77E150BC');
```

Then you could

```
String Foo = String('bar');
if (Foo == stringAppleUp ) {
...
```

Where Foo is what you want to test. NOTE the test of "==" versus the assignment of "="

Alternatively

```
char foo[] = "12345678";
if (strcmp(stringAppleUp, foo)) {
...
```

where you can find [strcmp of arrays here](http://www.nongnu.org/avr-libc/user-manual/group__avr__string.html#ga46f3cbd2de457c0fb340a1f379fc33ba)

Finally, a HEX is not a string, but an integer. Just test the results.value. Against another integer.

```
#include <IRremote.h>

int RECV_PIN = 11;
IRrecv irrecv(RECV_PIN);
decode_results results;

void setup()
{

  Serial.begin(9600);
  irrecv.enableIRIn(); // Start the receiver
}

void loop() {

  if (irrecv.decode(&results)) {
    Serial.print(F("result = 0x"));
    Serial.println(results.value, HEX);

    if (results.value == 0x77E150BC)  {
      Serial.println("yes");
    }
    else {
      Serial.println("No");
    }
    irrecv.resume(); // Receive the next value
  }
}
```